# PYTHON: How to make sure biggest number ALWAYS divide the smallest number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quick question:
Was wondering how to make sure ; when doing a division calculation so that the LARGEST NUMBER will always divide the SMALLEST number.

my friend told me it's like:

```
abs(Number1/Number2)
```

Is the code above correct?

Or is there another method to make sure it wiill work. :)

Comment: Nope, the code is not correct, your friend is confusing things with subtraction.

Comment: Do you really mean division or subtraction?

Comment: Best answer has already been chosen, thanks for your contribution! ;)

Comment: First think, then ask a friend, then try it with some numbers and see it correct or not. Then think again on this simple problem. Then ask it here. However if you passed 14 years (which I hope you don't) asking questions like this, coding is probably not for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly `min(a, b)/max(a, b)` should be ok.

EDITED: `max(a, b)/min(a, b)` does same thing oposite way

Comment: I think you have that backwards.

Comment: CAnnot thanks you enough for the quick answer! So simple and working perfectly!, i have tried this code by using the number 20 and 10 ,,,either way the result was '2'.  request close

Comment: Hmm. If one read the original post using standard English, then it would look more like max (a, b, c...)/ min (a, b, c...). "Largest" and "smallest" being superlatives, after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplicating the variable names and creating new variables

```
from operator import div
result = div(*sorted((Number1, Number2), reverse=True))
```

eg.

```
>>> div(*sorted((10, 5), reverse=True))
2

>>> div(*sorted((5, 10), reverse=True))
2
```

Usually it's going to be better to do something like this

```
small, big = sorted((Number1, Number2))
result = big / small
```